# How to load data from local sqlite db faster in Android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-fragments

I have about 300 records with multiple columns in sqlite db which I have to display in different textviews of a fragment. So, while switching from one fragment to that very fragment then it loads slowly (it takes around 15 seconds or so to display those data). What can be remedy to load the fragment faster?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think it's problem with sqlite, getting data from sqlite is very fast. You are probably doing some other time-consuming actions like http request.

Comment: @bipeen ..... asylume is correct ... time taking task might be related to your http request .... check your code !

Comment: Why are you trying to load all records? Do you need to display all of them at the same time?

Comment: thnks for the suggestions
no my codes just have loop to create some text views dynamically and i set the them with values from database.
am creating task scheduler so the fragment has all the tasks list to be displayed

Comment: 15 seconds seems really long and I guess you are doing something else that take a while. even you have 3000 records, it should not take that long. Please provide you code here for more help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to load all data at once, you need to look into "Lazy Loading" pattern, where you getting data on demand, when it really need to show up on the screen.

Here is one of many implementations - [android-lazyloading-cursor](https://github.com/esmasui/android-lazyloading-cursor)